# Downloading canvas image in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working in a small angular 2 app and i'm having the next problem:
I need the client browser to download a base64 image. I've been looking on internet for an answer but non of them seems to work...

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" (click)="download(this)" download="{{image.name}}.jpg">
    <p>download</p>
</a>
```

One of the answers i found is the above. Using a link and a click event with the next function:

```
download(element){
    element.href = BASE64 JPEG IMAGE FROM CANVAS;
    return;
}
```

This doesn't work, seems like the link is executed BEFORE the new href is set.
But in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/V6ufG/2/) works just fine, so i know i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `this` inside of that template!

Do it like this:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" #downloadLink (click)="download(downloadLink)" download="{{image.name}}.jpg">
    <p>download</p>
</a>
```

With this `#` syntax inside your template, you will create an local variable inside of your template. You can use this variable all over the template!

Comment: Not it work!, but i have to fix a problem with the canvas convertion. Thanks!